# why email value stored as %email in mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am so new in making project, so please don't mind. i created a code using php, html, css to store some data into mysql database. Everything is fine but the email value is stored as %email in the database. Can anybody help me please.

html code for email field:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="label">Email Id</div>
        <div class="inputaddr">
            <input type="text" id="email" required="required" class="detail" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="label">Category</div>
        <div class="inputmobile">
            <input type="text" id="category" required="required" class="shortdetail" name="category"/>
        </div>                  
    </div> <!-- end of 5th row -->
```

.php file:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db('ssitdashboard', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $raddr = $_POST['raddr'];
    $laddr = $_POST['laddr'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $bloodgroup = $_POST['bloodgroup'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $rmobile = $_POST['rmobile'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $usn = $_POST['usn'];
    $branch = $_POST['branch'];
    $sem = $_POST['sem'];
    $eca = $_POST['eca'];
    $year = $_POST['years'];
    $quota = $_POST['quota'];

    $que = "INSERT INTO personal_details(name, fname, mname, raddr, laddr, email, sex, dob, blood_group, mobile, rmobile, category, usn, branch, sem, eca, year, quota) VALUES ('$fullname', '$fname', '$mname', '$raddr', '$laddr', '%email', '$sex', '$dob', '$bloodgroup', '$mobile', '$rmobile', '$category', '$usn', '$branch', '$sem', '$eca', '$year', '$quota')";
    if(mysql_query($que)){
//          echo "<script>alert('You have registered successfully')</script>";
//          echo "<script>window.open('http://www.ssit.edu.in')</script>";  
        header("Location:thankyou.html");
        exit;

    }

}

?>
```

In database the email field is taken as varchar(30)

Comment: can you post your code as that would be helpful in debugging the problem ?

Comment: The line where you prepare and/or execute the query is the part that's important here.

Comment: What is your question? Why it's stored under a name of %email? That's your decision, not the database's decision...

Comment: I mean whatever i entered in email field it is stored as %email..

Comment: Before you do **anything** else, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here. You should also not be using `mysql_query` in new code, it's deprecated, dangerous if used as you have, and will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: I got it...sorry friends

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `%email` to `$email` in your SQL statement.

But, in addition, look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as this implementation is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

To elaborate on the PDO implementation, you could do something like this for your situation:

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "ssitdashboard";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try{
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}catch(PDOException $ex){
   die("Failed to connect: ".$ex->getMessage());
}
```

Now you have a PDO connection stored in `$db` which you can query through. You may want to account for [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) if you're not using PHP 5.4, so keep that in mind.

Otherwise, create your query statement like so..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO personal_details ( name, fname, mname, raddr, laddr, email, sex, dob, blood_group, mobile, rmobile, category, usn, branch, sem, eca, year, quota ) VALUES ( :name, :fname, :mname, :raddr, :laddr, :email, :sex, :dob, :blood_group, :mobile, :rmobile, :category, :usn, :branch, :sem, :eca, :year, :quota )"
```

Afterwards, you want to bind the values from the `$_POST` variables to the parameters that have `:` in front of them (like `:name`). You do that like so:

```
$query_params = array( ':name' => $_POST['fullname'], ':fname' => $_POST['fname'], ':mname' => $_POST['mname'], ':raddr' => $_POST['raddr'], ':laddr' => $_POST['laddr'], ':email' => $_POST['email'], ':sex' => $_POST['sex'], ':dob' => $_POST['dob'], ':blood_group' => $_POST['bloodgroup'], ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'], ':rmobile' => $_POST['rmobile'], ':category' => $_POST['category'], ':usn' => $_POST['usn'], ':branch' => $_POST['branch'], ':sem' => $_POST['sem'], ':eca' => $_POST['eca'], ':year' => $_POST['years'], ':quota' => $_POST['quota']);
```

Finally, now that you have the statement and the parameters, use the previously created `$db` variable to prepare and execute the statement.

```
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $statement->execute($query_params);
```

Since we're just `INSERT`ing variables into the database, that should be all that's needed. If you were `SELECT`ing data though, you could do something like this AFTER you've done the above...

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
```

And now you could refer to column headers within each `$row` of the database table by utilizing a foreach statement.

```
$bloodArray = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
   if(isset($row['blood_group'])){
       $bloodArray[] = $row['blood_group'];
   }
}
```

Hope that helps out, sorry for the delay!

Comment: one more thing should i use PDO implementation as if($_POST['submit']){//PDO.....} I mean after making connection

Comment: I would verify that the $_POST elements you're using exist before using them in a SQL statement. So, instead of `$_POST['submit']`, maybe you could do `if(isset($_POST['fullname'],$_POST['fname'],$_POST['mname'])){ }` With all the `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your query, `%email` where you intended `$email`.

That being said, you should rip out **all** of this code and replace it with something that doesn't have gigantic SQL injection bugs in it. Either you **must** use `mysql_real_escape_string` on each and every `$_POST` value being inserted, or you should be using PDO.

Mistakes like this are a lot harder to make if you have parameterized queries. An example in PDO is:

```
# Using named data placeholders here
$pdo->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO personal_details(name, fname, mname, raddr, laddr,
    email, sex, dob, blood_group, mobile, rmobile, category, usn,
    branch, sem, eca, year, quota)
  VALUES (:fullname, :fname, :mname, :raddr, :laddr,
    :email, :sex, :dob, :bloodgroup, :mobile, :rmobile, :category, :usn,
    :branch, :sem, :eca, :year, :quota)";

# When executing you specify the data to be used. The same prepared statement can be
# executed many times with different data.
$pdo->execute(array('fullname' => $_POST['fullname'], 'fname' => $_POST['fname'], ...));
```

Comment: @tadman...how to mysql_real_escape_string for my code? don't mind as i said I am new in php

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend switching to PDO because `mysql_query` is an ancient artifact that has no business being in new applications. Otherwise you'd need to replace every instance of `$_POST['x']` with `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x'])` which can be a big nuisance. See this link on [how to escape things properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Sorry to be so harsh, but this is very important. If you have an application on the internet, it can be utterly destroyed if you forget to do this correctly. Also it means your application won't crash if people have a name like `O'Malley`.

Answer (score 1):

mistake is that i used %email in the query...